# Is it useful to apply edge detection filter as a preprocessing step before applying CNN?

Tags: image-processing, filters, machine-learning, deep-learning

Background: my future boss would like me to apply a number of low level filters to industrial images before applying machine learning methods on them.
From my knowledge this doesn't make any sense as CNN will learn to do exactly the same, making the process redundant, in the best case, and counterproductive in the average case, as it will alter the natural information, reducing the original entropy. Moreover this could introduce technical problems in the learning chain as the version of the learnt ANN will depend on the version of the preprocessor, etc.

Is there any reason to apply such kind of filters before CNN?

Comment: I suspect it might benefit accelerating training time, if the filters happen to match to those that CNN must learn

Comment: MimSaad I agree with you, but that's a big if. Moreover to design such filters, you need to already know how the network will learn, hence the learning itself becomes redundant/useless.

Answer (score 1):

Feature extraction is operation we can model as increasing SNR by dropping information with low SNR.
Namely we extract relevant information and try to drop less relevant information. But always we lose some infomration.

So in cases most of the information is in the edges you'll certainly assist the CNN and probably shorten the training.

Yet, the main idea of Deep Learning is that the net is doing the feature engineering by itself.
It might be that in your context there is better feature to extract and possibly, if the architecture supports it, with enough data the net will figure it out.

So the balance is the optimality of the feature engineering vs. the need of lengthy training and many samples.